# How can I get panelSnap plugin to work with element inside a wrapper

Tags: jquery, scrolltop, vertical-scrolling

I tried the panelSnap plugin and got it working when the elements I wish to scroll to are within the  tag.

But when i'm trying the same thing but with elements inside a wrapper it's not working anymore.

With Chrome I got this error message:
'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined '

I've created a jsFiddle to make sure i'm not crazy!
http://jsfiddle.net/7K2CT/6/

```
var options = {
    $menu: $('header .menu'),
    panelSelector: 'section.panel',
    directionThreshold: 200,
    slideSpeed: 500
};
$('#wrapper').panelSnap(options);
```

Comment: same issue here. did you figure this out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, add these styles to your wrapper:

```
position: absolute;
overflow: scroll;
```

Then take out `panelSelector: 'section.panel'` from your options, and it should work. You may want to fine tune your options afterwards. [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ringstaff/MtRUR/3/).